# Is there a way to use numpy array functions to get this same effect?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to filter out all non-gray values within a given tolerance with the following code. It gives the expected results but runs too slowly to use in practice. Is there a way to do the following using numpy operations?

```py
for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            r, g, b = im_arr[i][j]

            r = (r + 150) / 2
            g = (g + 150) / 2
            b = (b + 150) / 2

            mean = (r + g + b) / 3
            diffr = abs(mean - r)
            diffg = abs(mean - g)
            diffb = abs(mean - b)

            maxdev = 2

            if (diffr + diffg + diffb) > maxdev:
                im_arr[i][j][0] = 0
                im_arr[i][j][1] = 0
                im_arr[i][j][2] = 0
```

Comment: you need to _try_ to solve your own question, not just ask it and expect your work be done for you. please review [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping in plain Python is slow: one of the advantages of `numpy` is that
transversing the arrays is highly optimized. Without commenting on the algorithm, you can get the same results using only `numpy`, which will be much faster

Since `im_arr` is an image, it is very likely that the `dtype` is `np.uint8`.
That is only 8 bits, so you have to be careful of overflows. In you code, when you add 150 to a number, the result will be of type `np.int64`. But if you add 150 to an 8-bit `np.ndarray`, the result will still be of type `np.uint8` and it can overflow.
You can either change the array type (using `astype`) or add a float, which will automatically promote the array to `float`

```py
mod_img = (im_arr + 150.)/2  # the point of "150." is important
signed_dif = mod_img - np.mean(mod_img, axis=2, keepdims=True)
collapsed_dif = np.sum(np.abs(signed_dif), axis=2)
maxdev = 2
im_arr[collapsed_dif > maxdev] = 0
```

Comment: Thank you, chose this answer as the solution as it was cleaner. I had no idea you could index elements like that.

Comment: See [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing), @Michael

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without any loop. I'll try to break out every step into a dedicated line

```py
import numpy as np
im_arr = np.random.rand(300,400,3) # Assuming this how you image looks like
img_shifted = (im_arr + 15) / 2 # This can be done in one go
mean_v = np.mean(img_shifted, axis=2) # Compute the mean along the channel axis
diff_img = np.abs(mean_v[:,:,None] - img_shifted) # Broadcasting to subtract n x m from n x m x k
maxdev = 2
selection = np.sum(diff_img, axis=2) > maxdev
im_arr[selection] = 0 # Using fancy indexing with booleans
```